# MIP- If then with either or

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I need something like this
It may sound silly but I couldn't find a way to express this.

x,te,ts decision variables, x bool, te,ts >=0;

if $x[m,i]+x[m,j]-1 > 0$
then
either $te[i]+d-ts[j]<=0$ or $te[j]+d-ts[i]<=0$;

If this was only either or I can make it with big-$M$ method, or I can convert an if then to either or, but I have a nested situtiation

Is it possible to express this in a linear programming model? Or maybe my decision variables are wrong.

Comment: Not sure to understand... but you can convert an "if..., then..." into and "either... or...". "if P, then Q" is the same as "either not-P or Q".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to assign jobs to machines, and if jobs $i$ and $j$ both get assigned to machine $m$ then you want to process job $i$, wait $d$ units, and process job $j$, or vice versa.  You can do this by introducing binary variables $p_{ij}$ for $i \not= j$, together with linear constraints:
\begin{align}
x_{m,i} + x_{m,j} - 1 &\le p_{ij} + p_{ji} &&\text{for all $m$ and $i < j$} \tag1 \\
te_i + d - ts_j &\le M_{ij} (1 - p_{ij}) &&\text{for $i \not= j$} \tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces $x_{m,i} \land x_{m,j} \implies p_{ij} \lor p_{ji}$, and constraint $(2)$ enforces $p_{ij} \implies te_i + d \le ts_j$.

Comment: Thank you, it was multiple machines to multiple jobs (different type of jobs so certain machines can do only certain jobs) with setup times, 
For anyone wondering I introduced a new variable as Rob suggested
y[m,i,j]=> job i precedes job j on machine m      and it did the trick

Comment: Glad to help.  Do you also have one machine per job, like $\sum_m x_{m,i}=1$ for all $i$?

Comment: Well there is 7 kind of jobs but 6 kind of machines, job 3,5 has common machine (truck), they need multiple trucks depends on how much product you extracted from process, I can share it after april 12 if you are interested, (it is my term project on operations research)